# PhpStorm color scheme

Tags: phpstorm, color-scheme

Just curious - which setting would affect the background color of strings like the following in my IDE (PhpStorm)?:

[image]

Comment: Based on colors ... you most likely have a Warning there (comes from SQL parser). Fixing the reason for the Warning should remove it (such highlighting). Or you want tot change colors for Warning?

Comment: @LazyOne I'll check out whether or not it's a warning, thanks for that!

Comment: @LazyOne That was it! Thank you!